# AS3: Save Data similar to how cookieClicker saves data

Tags: actionscript-3, load, save

I'm fairly new to any coding whatsoever, and the game I'm working on is somewhat similar to how cookie clicker works. Nothing but number data, and booleans.

For reference: http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

I pretty much want to be able to save my data with a long string of text so I'm not restricted to just playing on one computer.

Is there a way to do this with flash?

Also, if any of you rad guys n' gals have a better way of having a portable save that's simpler, I would be greatly appreciative!

Excuse my noobenocity, and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a SharedObject.

You can find and example of usage here :
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/